# Change last modified date in a Flow

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, lastmodifieddate

I have a Flow run once by system administrator to update a custom field in all existing records. But I do not want to update the Last Modified By or Last Modified Date fields. How can I do this?
I believe it can be done in Data Loader.

I tried this:
Give system administrator Set Audit Fields on Record Creation permission (has no effect, for creation only it seems)

In my flow, from in a loop I call Get Record, then set the custom field with an Assignment element, and then call UpdateRecord.

I added these fields to the Get Record element but did not change them in the Assignment element.

- LastModifiedById
- LastModifiedDate

Currently the changes have no effect and the last modified date gets updated.

Comment: I saw elsewhere on the net that possibly you can raise a case with Salesforce to enable Edit Audit Fields. I am not sure but it does not sounds like Data Loader needs this to update the last modified date. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done.

Only on record create and only when using Data Loader can you coerce the `LastModifiedDate` to be something other than `now`

[Set Audit Field Values](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328426&type=1&mode=1)

> Since these fields are intended to be audit fields, it is only possible to set them on record create and not update.

By definition, LastModifiedDate is an *audit field* and if one could manipulate it in code, it would cease to be an audit field.

If you have other processes that depend on LastModifiedDate you should consider using a different Datetime field that you control that said other processes can inspect